# Cannot kill pid 1 inside docker container with SIGKILL

Tags: python, docker, signals

For a reason, I want to kill the main python process ( PID 1 ) in docker container. But non of the terminating signals such as `SIGTERM`, `SIGKILL` work. I mean, running `kill -SIGKILL 1` has no effect.
How can I kill the pid 1 **from the inside of container**? I do not want to run `docker stop` or similar solutions.

Comment: SIGKILL won't be delivered to PID 1 that way (instead you may activate some handler, but that's something to experiment with)

Comment: How can I kill the PID 1? ( the last solution is running the python code via `entrypoint.sh` so the python code won't be the PID 1)

Comment: I found that SIGSEGVing it is an effective solution in most cases.

Comment: And really, killing the pid 1 will kill the entire container

Comment: `SIGSEGV` didn't affect a my multithreaded python code.

Comment: Then you should still remember that killing pid 1 kills the whole container. That's how the kernel implementation works.

Comment: And sometimes it's completely ok. For example in tests

Answer (score 1):

According to the Docker issue tracker and how the general documentation of pid 1s state, you need to specifically add a handler to the signals and kill the process from them.

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_gracefully)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_gracefully)
```

`exit_gracefully` needs to be defined and eventually call `sys.exit(0)`.

This behaviour is wanted and enforced by the kernel as it will not call the `sigaction` default, which is is termination, on the other pids.

We need to do something similar in Node.js.